# How to ignore a file without deleting it when switching git branches?

Tags: git, config, gitignore

I'm working on a PHP application where each developer has their own config.yml which contains passwords we don't want to put into a repo, so the file has been added to .gitignore. The problem is that each time I switch branches my config.yml disappears and I need to restore it from backup. How do I keep the file out of the repo without getting it removed every time I swap branches?

Comment: Is it a tracked file? Please add more details to the question - git doesn’t delete untracked files when changing branches.

Comment: what do you use to switch branches ?